# Mule jython running with main

Tags: java, xml, mule, jython

> Problem:

How to run a jython having main function in Mule application?

```
Issue:
```

I have a simple Jython code invoked by mule flow.

Flow:

```
<mule xmlns:... 
   <flow name="wfileFlow1" doc:name="wfileFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="===\n START ===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Python">
            <scripting:script engine="jython" file="src/main/java/com/test/Test1.py"/>
        </scripting:component>
        <logger message="===\n END ===" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

> Test1.py

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def addFixedValue(a):
  y = 5
  return y +a

print add(1,2)
print addFixedValue(1)
```

output:

```
===\n START ===
3
6

===\n END ===
```

if I run with main, then no output i.e it doesn't print anything.

> Test1.py

```
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

def addFixedValue(a):
  y = 5
  return y +a

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      print add(3,4)
      print addFixedValue(1)
```

It prints no jython values:

```
 ===\n START ===

 ===\n END ===
```

Note here no jython values are printed.

Issue is, since second one run as main program in Java, but how do I run a main program from mule application if my above flow is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`__name__` variable is [just a Python interpreter hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for executing sections in a main source file (and ignoring them in imported modules). Mule sets the value of `__name__` to `main` when running Jython scripts, so I guess you could do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__' or __name__ == 'main':
```